# Does any engine combine an air-breathing rocket and a non-air-breathing rocket?

Tags: engine, hypersonic, rocket

Does any rocket engine combine air-breathing and non-air-breathing modes?

The advantage would be it would have to carry a smaller tank and less oxygen, leaving more room for payload on a weight basis.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SABRE_(rocket_engine)).

Comment: @Sanchises the SABRE is still in development.

Comment: @securitydude5 by definition, rocket engine is not air breathing. You should speak of jet engine.

Comment: @ManuH SABRE is described as an air-breathing rocket. That is exactly how its engine functions in airbreathing mode. It has no fans or through-duct, what it has is a rocket chamber fed by fuel and oxidant.

Comment: I fail to see why this question is closed. Yes it is an overlap between space.SE and aviation.SE. Aircrafts with rocket engines exist (e.g. the Me163), thus rocket engines are on topic here. Why can't our community accept overlaps?

Comment: There are cases when air breaching and non air breaching stages are used (X-15, SpaceShipOne and Two, Lockheed D-21 is air breaching, then pure rocket, then air breaching drone again). But not in the same engine.

Comment: @Manu H: I suspect it's closed because (as written) it asks a nonsensical question.  There is no such thing as an air-breathing rocket, BY DEFINITION.  Air-breathing reaction engines are jet engines.  It could be re-written to ask several different questions, e.g. "Is there an engine that switches from jet to rocket?", or "Are there space launch systems that use both jets and rockets?"

Answer (score 2):

There's a very recent claim for an engine called Fenris, which claims to be a no-moving-parts "rocket" that uses ambient air for its oxidizer.

On the face, that sounds like a ramjet, but the claims made by the inventors appear (to me) to be investor bait, rather than anything that could actually be true.  Video on the entry page at the inventor's web site shows a burn more like that of a poorly designed torch, than a rocket or jet.

As noted in comments, there is also the SABRE engine concept -- this is not yet a working engine, as far as I know, but will/would be a hydrogen-fueled turbo-ramjet which uses the liquid hydrogen to liquefy intake air while in jet mod, for use as oxidizer when it switches to rocket mode.  The intent is for use as a spaceplane-to-orbit.

Comment: A no moving parts rocket that uses ambient air, it sounds like a ramjet.

Comment: @ManuH Go look up the Fenris "rocket" -- their claims aren't  calling it a ramjet, and they seem to think they can convince investors it'll work.  Physically, the engine they have looks much like a rocket thrust chamber and nozzle.

Comment: SABRE uses liquid *helium* to cool the air to *near (just above)* its liquefaction point. This is then turbo-compressed and fed as oxidant to a conventional hydrogen-fuelled rocket chamber. The intent is to first find sub-orbital applications, with orbital flight being a longer-term aspiration. Currently the individual engine subsystems have all been bench-tested, notably the pre-cooler, and development of a flight demonstrator is starting.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Been a while since I looked at the SABRE.  Now they want to carry a second cryogenic liquid?  One they don't even burn off, so have to carry all the way?  Seems like trying to save a concept that didn't work as expected...

Comment: @ZeissIkon The helium intermediary has been in the design for a long time now. It has a complex thermodynamic function in utilising the waste heat to help drive the rest of the system. More like making practical a concept that was not quite figured out in the early days. There are other significant changes too, but design details seem scarcer than they used to be.

Comment: Had a quick look at Fenris.  It isn't a ramjet.  It gets its air by sucking it in rather than having it forced in by motion.  The idea seems to be that it creates a (partial) vacuum inside the combustion chamber that sucks air in through the the inlet.  I have no idea how that would work.

Comment: @JRE poorly, in my opinion.  It's the same idea behind the Gluhareff jet, which is just a high-frequency pulsejet with a fluidic valve.  Requires very high fuel pressure to run a deLaval nozzle to get supersonic fuel flow and entrain combustion air.  I don't see much that looks like thrusting exhaust in the little clip of video I've seen -- not even as much as a Gluhareff produces.

Comment: There is a hybrid concept that uses solid fuel in the rocket motor but liquid oxygen as the oxidizer; in this case you can vary the thrust of the motor by varying the oxygen flow rate. in this case you have to carry the oxygen with you however...

Comment: Hybrids like that have been around a good while -- they were available for High Power model rocketry twenty years ago (using nitrous oxide as self-pressurizing oxidizer).  But they're still rockets, not jets.